# Show data entry form as dialog asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have "add new folder" button in my asp.net form and I need to show dialog in order to make the user able to enter the folder name, how can I accomplish that in asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

Add an `OnClientClick="ShowPopup();return false;"` to the button, and then do:

```
function ShowPopup() {
  var div = document.getElementById("divtoshow");
  div.style.display = "block";
}
```

In the pure form, and then make the div absolute position and reposition the popup to center over the button.  Are you using JQuery?  You could use JQuery dialog, or use JQuery to position the element, or if you are using AJAX Control toolkit, use the ModalPopupExtender.  There are options, but it's hard to tell without knowing what you are using.

HTH.

Comment: pure form means the data entry one?

Comment: Pure JavaScript without any JavaScript libraries,etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options.

1. You could include the textbox on the form so that the new folder name is already included.
2. You could redirect the user to a new form to enter the new folder name.
3. You could use javascript to include #2 as a thickbox on the current page.

There are other options, it's all in how you want to do it

**Update:** To accomplish #3, you would have to make another asp.net page, and use a library like [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) and load an IFrame inside the thickbox/lightbox